# Jenkins: Is there a way to display userContent file timestamp details in browser?

Tags: jenkins

We have a fairly straight-forward Jenkins instance with inter-dependent jobs.

In order to move artifacts from one job to another, we make use of the *%JENKINS-HOME%/userContent* folder and the *Copy Artifact* plugin.

That is, we copy some files from the  result of a build into the *userContent* folder and then the next job picks these up and continues.

The default Jenkins UI allows you to see the folders and files in the *userContent* folder along with their filesizes, but is there a way to indicate their creation time/date?